# js - how to default to a specific value if target value does not met

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry to post this question but I'm kinda newbie when it comes to `js`. I have created a simple page that will compute charging transactions, so what it will do is to simply multiply the `Quantity` and `Price` to `.25%`. But here is the trick, if the total product is less than `50` the `Charge` field should default to `50` and that's where I'm kinda lost,

here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td width="144">Quantity:</td>
    <td width="63"><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" size="8"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Price:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" size="8"/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><strong>Charges:</strong></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Charge:</td>
    <td><input style="color:#F00" type="text" name="charge" id="charge" size="8" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td colspan="2">Quantity x Price x .25% OR 20 whichever is higher</td>
</tr>
```

here is the `js` that i managed to have,

```
    $(function () {
        $("#quantity, #price").keyup(function () {
            var q = parseFloat($("#quantity").val()); // Quantity
            var p = parseFloat($("#price").val()); // Price
            if (isNaN(q) || isNaN(p) || q<=0 || p <= 0) {
                $("#charge").val('');
                return false;
            }
            $("#charge").val((q * p * 0.0025).toFixed(3)); // Charge
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where do you multiply the quantity and price? Just put an `if(total < 50)` after that to set the default total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the total in a variable and test it before putting it into the DOM:

```
$(function () {
    $("#quantity, #price").keyup(function () {
        var q = parseFloat($("#quantity").val()); // Quantity
        var p = parseFloat($("#price").val()); // Price
        if (isNaN(q) || isNaN(p) || q<=0 || p <= 0) {
            $("#charge").val('');
            return false;
        }
        var total = q * p * 0.0025;
        if (total < 50) {
            total = 50;
        }
        $("#charge").val(total.toFixed(3)); // Charge
    });
});
```

Another way is to use `Math.max()`:

```
$("#charge").val(Math.max(50, q * p * 0.0025).toFixed(3)); // Charge
```